# T-SQL Check for column with IF NOT EXISTS in stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with `IF NOT EXISTS` statement. I have used the following code inside of using a stored procedure:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                         WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableName'
                         AND COLUMN_NAME = @fieldName
                         AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')   
BEGIN  
       DECLARE @paramDefinitions NVARCHAR(1000)

    SET @paramDefinitions=
     '@dataType nvarchar(100) OUTPUT'
        SET @typeQuery = 'SELECT @dataType =
                  CASE 
                  WHEN s.name = ''nvarchar'' THEN ''nvarchar('' + CAST(c.max_length AS varchar(4)) + '')'' 
                      WHEN s.name = ''varchar'' THEN ''varchar('' + CAST(c.max_length AS varchar(4)) + '')''
                      WHEN s.name = ''char'' THEN ''char('' + CAST(c.max_length AS varchar(4)) + '')''
              WHEN s.name = ''nchar'' THEN ''nchar('' + CAST(c.max_length AS varchar(4)) + '')''
             ELSE s.name 
              END                 
            FROM sys.views t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id 
                              JOIN sys.types s ON c.user_type_id = s.user_type_id 
            WHERE t.name = ''tablename'' AND c.name =' + @tmpField

            EXEC sp_executesql @typeQuery, @paramDefinitions, @dataType OUTPUT

            SET @updateTable = 'Alter table dbo.tablename add ' + @field +' '+ @dataType 
            print @updateTable

        EXEC sp_executesql @updateTable  
END
```

If I now start the SP it tries to recreate the already existing columns, but it will also create any new column. If I change it to `IF EXISTS`it won't do anything.

If I run the select statement by itself I get a 1 as a result if the column exists and nothing if it doesn't. Where is my mistake? Is it not possible to use `IF NOT EXISTS` for this purpose?

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code? For example the "Create field" fragment, or perhaps the entire stored procedure if possible.

Comment: Show code between `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: Updated the initial post with the requested information

Comment: Are all variables set within your exists block? Try to print all the variables inside, in my case the code always worked (that is, the exists block is being executed). But what i saw was that my datatype variable was empty/NULL, so i don't get the statements properly.

Comment: I do set/declare some variables outside of the exists block as I need to do it in order to have the right values ready

Comment: In the select you use `@fieldname` and in the alter table you use `@field`. Do they contain the same value?

Comment: No they don't `@fieldName` is `'Field Name'` and `@field` is `[Field Name]`. The main problem I've there is that a field name can contain spaces

Comment: When you say `@fieldName` is `'Field Name'` do you mean the value you are storing literally contains the single quotes as part of the value?

Comment: Yes that's the case as it was the only way I got it somehow working (It more looks like not as we see now :) )

Comment: Try changing just the `@fieldName` value to remove the single quotes. Leave the `@field` value as is with the brackets around the value.

Comment: Tried that but the statement doesn't work anymore if I remove the single quotes

Comment: i have the same question also, the block _if not exist_ and _if exist_ execute anyway. the whole context of code between begin end

Answer (score 1):

If I want to check if a table contains some column, I use **COLUMNPROPERTY**:

```
IF COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[TABLE]'), 'COLUMN_NAME', 'AllowsNull') is NULL
BEGIN
SELECT 'The column does not exists'
END
```

Comment: If I use columnproperty it doesn't create anything. I also get no result if I try print the result: print COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[t_hist_Devicereport]'), @tmpField, 'AllowsNull') . I think my problems are the spaces in the fieldnames...

Comment: Are you able to check COLUMNPROPERTY without using @tmpField variable?

Comment: No as this check happens inside of a cursor and the variable is the result from the fetch next from the cursor

Comment: If @tmpField is varchar you could put raiserror(@tmpField,11,1) to see the value. Just checked the code on my environment: it works fine even if you pass the parameter with spaces. It should return NULL if the column doesn't exist in the specified table.

Comment: I just tried this but I don't get an error and it doesn't add any columns

Comment: Does your condition look like: IF COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[t_hist_Devicereport]'), @tmpField, 'AllowsNull') IS NULL BEGIN ....... ? It seems condition is false and you even cannot reach raiserror(). Well, if it's false then column exists! Put raiserror() (or print, if you prefer it) before the condition. At least we will know which column is going to be checked

Comment: I found the mistake in my previous try and it works now the same way as the IF NOT EXISTS solution. It also tries to add columns that are already there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23502/discussion-between-nja-and-andrey-gordeev)